# How to respond to HTTP request with html AND attachment?

Tags: http, attachment, content-disposition

How can I respond to a HTTP request with the HTML of a page as well as an attachment?

For example you navigate to /start_download

The page says "Thank you for downloading!"

And the browsers prompts for save as without navigating somewhere else.

I know how to use "Content-Disposition: attachment; filname=file.txt" but I don't know if it's possible to load a page before the attachment (i.e mixed response for one request).

If it helps, I'm using Python's BaseHTTPRequestHandler.

P.S: Other web servers, etc... are not an option as this is homework specifications.

Answer (score 3):

If you add a tag like this to the header of the 'thank you page', then the browser does it for you.

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="3;URL=_url_with_attachment_" />
```

Then you make `_url_with_attachment_` serve up the download. The 3 is the number of seconds before it goes where you want it to.

If you really want to do it in the header without affecting the served HTML, then you would serve

```
Refresh: 3;URL=_url_with_attachment_
```

Comment: Thanks but my question is specifically about the structure of a HTTP response.

Comment: That *is* how you do it in HTTP. With a header. You can send the refresh as a header, but this is the modern way to do it. Look for 'http refresh header'.

Comment: are you sure it can't be done with a multipart HTTP response?

Comment: That depends whether you actually want it to work in all browsers.